Realistic Plastic texture
How can i make a plastic texture like this ? 

If you have the cap modeled, I would try using some subsurface scattering.
You can get rid of some of the unwanted shadows by mixing it with a transparend shader controlled by light path.
But I'm sure there are better ways...

